# SULU CMS - How to solve AWS log problem maxbanton/cwh with Symfony 6/PHP8

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, sulu, php-8.2

I have a project developed in [Sulu CMS v2.5.10](https://github.com/sulu/sulu), and I updated my Symfony to v6, and PHP to v8.2, and in project I have package:

[maxbenton/cwh v2.0.4](https://github.com/maxbanton/cwh)

App is returning next error:

```
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Maxbanton\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch::write(array $record): void must be compatible with Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::write(Monolog\LogRecord $record): void in /var/www/html/vendor/maxbanton/cwh/src/Handler/CloudWatch.php on line 164
!!  PHPERROR: 
!!  Fatal error: Declaration of Maxbanton\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch::write(array $record): void must be compatible with Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::write(Monolog\LogRecord $record): void in /var/www/html/vendor/maxbanton/cwh/src/Handler/CloudWatch.php on line 164
!!  Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#8833
!!    #message: "Compile Error: Declaration of Maxbanton\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch::write(array $record): void must be compatible with Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::write(Monolog\LogRecord $record): void"
!!    #code: 0
!!    #file: "./vendor/maxbanton/cwh/src/Handler/CloudWatch.php"
!!    #line: 164
!!    -error: array:4 [
!!      "type" => 64
!!      "message" => "Declaration of Maxbanton\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch::write(array $record): void must be compatible with Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::write(Monolog\LogRecord $record): void"
!!      "file" => "/var/www/html/vendor/maxbanton/cwh/src/Handler/CloudWatch.php"
!!      "line" => 164
!!    ]
!!  }
!!
```

Any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to

composer require phpnexus/cwh

PhpNexus\Cwh\Handler\CloudWatch